# Mysql create a row named Rank

Tags: php, mysql

Let me tell you an example from my question.
For example we have table named (order) that insert all orders and purchase to this table.

Table A (orders):

```
+--------------------------+
| CustomerKey | ProductKey |
+--------------------------+
| 306545      | pro1       |
| 597864      | pro3       |
| 784678      | pro2       |
| 905479      | pro3       |
| 306545      | pro1       |
| 348965      | pro3       |
| 784678      | pro3       |
+--------------------------+
```

Now i would like to order and get our Bestselling products
Query output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| id | ProductKey | numberSold  |
+-------------------------------+
| 1  | pro3       | 4           |
| 2  | pro1       | 2           |
| 3  | pro2       | 1           |
+-------------------------------+
```

I wrote i query for this:

```
select ProductKey, count(1) as numberSold from A group by ProductKey order by count(1) desc
```

but it is not complete! this query need to a row named rank (Look at the below query output):

```
+-------------------------------------+
| id | ProductKey | numberSold | rank |
+-------------------------------------|
| 1  | pro3       | 4          | 1    |
| 2  | pro1       | 2          | 2    |
| 3  | pro2       | 1          | 3    |
+------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: You want a _column_, not a _row_.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT 
    ProductKey, 
    count(1) AS numberSold, 
    @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank 
  FROM A 
  GROUP BY ProductKey ORDER BY numberSold DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

or... if you prefer the single query approach...

```
SELECT a.*
     , @rank:=@rank+1 rank 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT ProductKey
            , COUNT(1) numberSold
         FROM my_table
        GROUP 
           BY ProductKey 
     ) a
     , (SELECT @rank:=0) vars
 ORDER 
    BY numberSold DESC;
```